# Simple way to report errors to a user in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, error-handling, nlog

Right now in my app, I am logging all errors with `NLog`.  If the error is `level = ERROR`, I want to present the user with something, but allow them to continue, if it is `level = FATAL`, I also want to present the user with something, but tell them they need to shut down the app.  What is the simplest way to do this?  It doesn't need to be anything fancy.

Comment: messageBox? I can't think on anything simpler.

Comment: have you thought about wpf popup http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx

Comment: I thought about this and I assume you are referring to the Windows.Forms.MessageBox, correct?

Comment: no this is part of the wpf framework

Comment: There is also a [WPF MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Message Box Target for NLog](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/MessageBox_target) you may want to look into.

Comment: Cool, I added `<target xsi:type="MessageBox" name="errorMessageBox" layout="Layout" caption="Layout" />` and `<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorMessageBox" />` and threw an error on purpose in my app, but I did not get a message box.

Comment: I got it, I had 2 log files and it was being written to one, but not the other.  Thanks, this works great.